# Must film capacitors be derated according to the voltage applied?

Tags: capacitor, metal-film

I know electrolytic capacitors must be derated according to the applied voltage, with some losing a significant part of their nominal value at high voltages.

Is it a similar case with film capacitors? I am using these [TDK 1uF film capacitors](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/871-B32672P5105K000) . Will be applying 400Vdc on these.

I did try looking it up, I could not find a clear answer.

Comment: Datasheet specific to a series of capacitors should have those details, at least from reputable manufacturers.

Comment: It is rated for 520Vdc  
B32672P5105K000